# CSS for fit image to table cell with text overlay

Tags: html, css, background, html-table

Can someone one please give me a hand with the CSS for displaying an image as the background of a TD and fitting some text correctly over it.

It seems that for double digits works fine but with a single I am getting some clipping.
[image]

CSS:

```
.bkgImg {
  background: url('/Images/circle.png') no-repeat;
  background-size:32px 32px;
  padding: 6px 8px 6px 8px;
  color: white;
}
```

HTML:

```
    <table>
        <tr>
           <td class="bkgImg">50</td>
        </tr>
   </table>
```

[SEE LINK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k4RSo.png)

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7kM3R/

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle.net?

Comment: It´s table, TD size reflects their content. I´m not able to tell you more about without link to page/code incl.

Comment: Yeah, set the fixed size to the `bkgImg` class and you will be good :)

Comment: @sd_dracula - note it doesnt reflect stated behaviour: http://jsfiddle.net/7kM3R/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've updated your fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/7kM3R/7/

Here's full css for your class:

```
.bkgImg {
    background-image: url("http://www.charlespetzold.com/blog/2012/12/BezierCircleFigure3.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size:32px 32px;
    color: white;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Firstly I removed padding.
Then set fixed size for table cell (width&height):

```
width: 32px;
height: 32px;
```

and added background position (center)

```
background-position: center center;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
width: 15px;
text-align: center;
```

Adding these lines to ur css will give you an ans
check the impact in your fiddle which I have updated

Answer (score 1):

Your background image is cutted by the width of your `td` element. Give your `td` a fixed width and it will work. Have a look at this **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7kM3R/10/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can use `min-width` for `<td>` like this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/Rw3Qk/).

Answer (score 0):

you only need to set fixed block bkgImg `sizes width:32px; height:32px;` or change the `padding: 6px 11px;`

```
        .bkgImg {
            width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
  background: url("http://www.charlespetzold.com/blog/2012/12/BezierCircleFigure3.png") no-repeat;
  background-size:32px 32px;
  /*padding: 6px 8px 6px 8px;*/
  color: white;
    text-align:center;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7kM3R/15/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to specifiy `width` and `height`

You should avoid use `background-image` for circle but `border-radius`

```
.value {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    background-color: orange;
    color: white;
}
```

avoid also to use table for non tabular data

Answer (score 0):

Just change `background-size:32px 32px` to `background-size:100% 100%;`

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/7kM3R/5/)

Comment: I have tried it and as you can see it stretches the image which is what I don't want.

Comment: because the parent doesn't have enough space for showing your image.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set width and height of your  element. For example add:

```
bkgImg {
    width:450px;
    height:450px;
}
```

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/pndz/WFQLC/

Answer (score 0):

Add following css

```
.value {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
}
```